# Is Rebol suited to fill up on-line web forms?

Tags: rebol, rebol3

The title says it almost all.
There are tools like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) and [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit) that allow one to send text to fill up on-line web forms and process the the POST answer.

I know that Rebol can do the latter.  But what about the former?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [script I wrote](https://github.com/gchiu/Rebol3/blob/master/scripts/loginso.reb) which was to look at web forms, extract the various variables, and allow you to POST the form, and then capture the output.  This was just a test prior to figuring out how to automate the login to Stackoverflow which has since been done.